# guava collections conversion to scala collections

Tags: java, scala-collections, guava

Hi I'm writing some package in scala and I need to parse out public suffix from a url. Google Guava has a nice class InternetDomainName that does the job but it return a

```
com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList[String]
```

rather than

```
scala.collection.immutable.List[String]
```

I tried using guavapants but it didn't really help. Also, I was able to convert the Guava object into a Scala Array[Object] (using toArray) but I don't know how to move from there (I have found no way to convert this Object to String: netiher toString nor mkString nor new String() gave me what I wanted).

What I want is to get rid of this public suffix so any solution in scala that does it will be good: the ones that use Guava would be preferable though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but following code works just fine:

```
import com.google.common.collect.{ImmutableList}

val l = ImmutableList.of("A", "B", "C", "D")

val s = l.toArray(Array[String]()).mkString(",")
//s is now "A,B,C,D"
```